TensorFlow custom weights manipulation
So, I'm having difficulty with implementing custom modification of weights, which is not based on any of the standard TF-provided optimizers and doesn't care about gradient tape whatsoever.
Essentially, what I'm trying to achieve is to update weights of the neural network after each training iteration, independently of the built-in updates (I actually want to disable them altogether, in order to reduce the computational overhead).
For simplicity let's say I just want to add some random float to each weight. The key requirement is to be able to do it in parallel, because in this example (and in my actual logic) weight updates are independent from each-other.
How do I find an "entry point" to TF where I could specify my mathematical operation that should be performed in parallel on all the weights after each feed-forward fitting run?
I was looking into custom optimizers and even a writing a training loop from scratch article, but all these approaches seem to be heavily dependent on gradients, TF's built-int tape and some other things that I don't really need for my algorithm.
I've found a way of overwriting the weights of a given layer, which could help me, in this answer: How to set custom weights in layers? But I'm not sure where exactly should I place this code.

Hi, could you please provide minimal reproducible example.

Basically I would go with setting trainable=False for desired layers. And then update them manually after each optimizer.step

You can do whatever you want in a custom train_step you are overwriting. No need to compute gradients or even call the model. Just iterate over the weights and add random floats to each (for example).
